# solve readlink issue for bizapps-dev-box

Tags: installation, workspace

How to solve readlink issue for bizapps-dev-box and reference in a common way across macOS, Windows and Linux

```
ci/check_bats.bash -f .precondition

Test Filters 
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
/usr/bin/readlink: illegal option -- f
usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]
multipass-dev-box/test/libs/bats/libexec/bats-core/bats: line 171: exec: ba
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix bizapps-dev-box readlink issue in on Mac

In Terminal On Mac (Assuming [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) is already installed:

```
brew install coreutils
alias readlink=greadlink
```

Add the alias to ~/.bashrc for global settings

alias readlink=greadlink